# Unable to load a URL when using profiles in Firefox 44 using Selenium 2.51.0

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am using Firefox 44 on Ubuntu 12.04. I've got the Selenium Firefox Driver (Java 8) version 2.51.0.
It works fine with all my programs that use the default firefox profile.
However, I have a couple of programs that use a special Firefox profile, and these do not work.
The Firefox window opens, shows a blank page for a while, and then closes.
The error I get is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1455175741082   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping ubufox@ubuntu.com to /usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com.xpi
1455175741083   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1455175741083   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loaded add-on state from prefs: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"/tmp/anonymous1261823428052395525webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1455175734000,"mt":1455175734000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"44.0","st":1454293453000,"mt":1453731912000}},"app-system-share":{"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"3.2","st":1442597112000}}}
1455175741084   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
1455175741085   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1455175741085   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1455175741085   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of ubufox@ubuntu.com
1455175741086   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on ubufox@ubuntu.com in app-system-share
1455175741086   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"/tmp/anonymous1261823428052395525webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1455175734000,"mt":1455175734000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"44.0","st":1454293453000,"mt":1453731912000}},"app-system-share":{"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"3.2","st":1442597112000}}}
1455175741087   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1455175741095   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1455175741095   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1455175741096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1455175741096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1455175741096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1455175741096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1455175741102   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1455175741102   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1455175741102   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1455175741102   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1455175741102   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1455175741103   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1455175741142   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database /tmp/anonymous1261823428052395525webdriver-profile/extensions.json
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1455175741245   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1455175741245   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1455175741245   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1455175741325   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1455175741325   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1455175741326   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1455175741389   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1455175741389   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1455175741389   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
console.error: 
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
console.error: 
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at mainPackage.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:45)
```

Is there some incompatibility that I am unaware of?

The code that I am using is :

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("AutomationProfile");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("<some link>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to compatability issues between Firefox & Selenium. Suggestions would be:

1. Running an older Firefox version
2. If you use JDK 7, try switching it to JDK 6.

As i understand, it runs ok with the default profile and without knowing what do you have inside your new profile makes it hard to identify the real cause.